# S3 | Apply Encryption on Bucket but Exclude a Folder Inside

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

I wonder if I can apply an encryption on S3 buckets and all the existing and new files and folders will be encrypted. That's easy and I'm done with it. Now I have a need to exclude a particular directory from encryption and data uploaded in this particular directory should not be encrypted.

There's is an option for directories to change encryption. When I mark it to 'None', it's not having the impact. I'm applying AES-256 encryption on bucket.

What can be wrong? Or what is I'm missing? or How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

@Tausif, you can change encryption of the folder from action >change encryption then all affected objects will change encryption. If not you can got with Client-Side Encryption also.

Comment: I have that option but it's not working. Don't know if it's a bug :P